# Merge multiple array of hashes where a value matches in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have 3 arrays with multiple hashes that I am trying to convert into a single array of hashes where a key/value matches

```
a = [{"name"=>"aaa", "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2"}, {"name"=>"bbb", "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2"}]
b = [{"name"=>"aaa", "c"=>"1", "d"=>"2"}, {"name"=>"bbb", "c"=>"1", "d"=>"2"}]
c = [{"name"=>"aaa", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"2"}, {"name"=>"bbb", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"2"}]
```

to get

```
combined = [{"name"=>"aaa", "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "c"=>"1", "d"=>"2", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"2"}, {"name"=>"bbb", "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "c"=>"1", "d"=>"2", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"2"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need.

```rb
hashes = [a, b, c]
result = hashes.inject([]) do |result, hash_array|
  hash_array.each do |hash|
    index = result.find_index{|item| item["name"] == hash["name"]}
    if index
      result[index] = result[index].merge(hash)
    else
      result << hash
    end
  end
  result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This just looks cooler, and should still solve your case too:

```rb
a.zip(b,c).map{|vertical_array| e.inject({}) {|result, k| result.merge(k)} }
```

Console:

```
2.5.1 :016 > a.zip(b,c).map{|e|e.inject({}){|result, k| result.merge(k)} }
 => [{"name"=>"aaa", "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "c"=>"1", "d"=>"2", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"2"}, {"name"=>"bbb", "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "c"=>"1", "d"=>"2", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"2"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[a,b,c].transpose
       .map { |arr| arr.reduce(&:merge) }
  #=> [{"name"=>"aaa", "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "c"=>"1", "d"=>"2", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"2"},
       {"name"=>"bbb", "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "c"=>"1", "d"=>"2", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"2"}]
```

---

If the ordering of the elements of `a`, `b` and `c` is not guaranteed, one may write

```
[a,b,c].map { |arr| arr.sort_by { |h| h["name"] } }
       .transpose
       .map { |arr| arr.reduce(&:merge) }
```

or

```
(a+b+c).each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g["name"]=>g) { |_,o,n| o.merge(n) }
end.values
```

The latter uses the form of [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block (`{ |_,o,n| o.merge(n) }`) to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. Note that here the receiver of [Hash#values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-values) is

```
(a+b+c).each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g["name"]=>g) { |_,o,n| o.merge(n) }
end
  #=> {"aaa"=>{"name"=>"aaa", "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "c"=>"1",
  #            "d"=>"2", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"2"},
  #    "bbb"=>{"name"=>"bbb", "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "c"=>"1",
  #            "d"=>"2", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"2"}]
```

This calculation also permits greater variety in the content of the data. Suppose, for example:

```
a = [{"name"=>"aaa", "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2"}, {"name"=>"bbb", "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2"}]
b = [{"name"=>"bbb", "c"=>"1", "d"=>"2"}, {"name"=>"ccc", "c"=>"1", "d"=>"2"}]
c = [{"name"=>"ccc", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"2"}, {"name"=>"aaa", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"2"}]
```

Then

```
(a+b+c).each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g["name"]=>g) { |_,o,n| o.merge(n) }
end
  #=> {"aaa"=>{"name"=>"aaa", "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"2"},
  #    "bbb"=>{"name"=>"bbb", "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2", "c"=>"1", "d"=>"2"},
  #    "ccc"=>{"name"=>"bbb", "c"=>"1", "d"=>"2", "e"=>"1", "f"=>"2"}]
```